# Accessing 'public' facebook objects which still require a user token

Tags: facebook, oauth

Take for example

http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10150130077340815&set=vb.22092443056&type=2&theater

If I try and access that object in the graph explorer

https://graph.facebook.com/10150130077340815

I get an OAuthException which says I need a user token.

But if I just go to the above URL on the FB website, I can see the video just fine!

HOW can I programatically access objects like that -- where I can see when on Facebook-the-site without being logged in, but can't get  at them in code without an access token?

WHat incredibly simple thing am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You need an access token to access objects owned by other other objects when using the graph api

You can verify this by going [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=10150130077340815) and trying your query... it won't work.

Then, click on "Generate access token", try the same query (for 10150130077340815) and voila, you got starbucks stuff.

Get your access token and you should be able to do this. You might have to jump through some hoops getting it renewed if this has to be a completely thing.

Comment: Could be true of Google, but my question was regarding FaceBook ;-)

Comment: Your question was regarding using OAuth, which is very similar for both facebook and google. I don't think you're doing anything wrong with your query or fb-graph, I think it's the OAuth protocol. Try some queries in the facebook graph explorer when you have an access token vs when you don't